# transfer word-wraps from textarea to email

Tags: javascript, email, textarea, word-wrap

I have programmed a textarea with pre written text. With a button click, I want this text to appear in a 'ready to send' email. But when the email opens up, all word-warps are gone. You can put %0d%0a in the code to indicate that there needs to be a word-wrap in the email, but in this case the %0d%0a is also visible in the textarea. (\n and other codes do not work)

Is there a solution where you can define word-wraps that are not visible in an editable textarea, but result in word-wraps in the email?

I have tried a contentEditable div, but cant make it work right now. Would that be a solution? I can make it look like a textarea if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: just add a step and replace newline characters with %0d%0a before pasting

Comment: This works when I load the code in a browser. However, when I paste it to a wordpress site, %0d%0a is translated to <br>. The <br>s are visible in the textarea and even in the final email. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: add the <br> not in the textarea but after copying and before pasting to the email. is the final email plain text? make it html.